# jQuery toggle() working bottom to top, but not top to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the demo below, when in a mobile viewport `<=768px` I do the following:

1. Click on Product, to open Product's mega menu.
2. Scroll down, and click on Resources.
3. I expect Product's mega menu to close, and Resource's mega menu to open.
4. What happens is Product's mega menu closes, but Resource's mega menu doesn't open.

The problem doesn't exist working in the reverse order, i.e. opening Resource's mega menu first, then clicking on Product to close Resource's mega menu, and opening Product's mega menu (this works fine).

I've considered if an element is overlapping the correct item and preventing the right element from being clicked - I don't think this is the case.

You'll need to click the burger menu @ top right to see what happens.

Help appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    $(".mega-drop-down").hover(function() {
        $(this).find('a span').toggleClass('hover');
        $('.mega-menu').not($(this).children('.mega-menu').toggle()).hide();
        $('.exo-menu').find('a span').not($(this).find('a span')).removeClass('hover');
    });
}
$(".mega-drop-down").on('click', function () {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) { 
        $('.mega-menu').not($(this).children('.mega-menu').toggleClass('hide-block')).addClass('hide-block');
        $(this).find('a span').toggleClass('hover');
        $('.exo-menu').find('a span').not($(this).find('a span')).removeClass('hover');
    }
});
$('.toggle-menu').click(function(){
    $('.exo-menu').toggleClass('display');
    $('#mm-button-group').toggle();
});
});
```

```css
.fl-builder-content[data-type="header"].fl-theme-builder-header-sticky {
    z-index: 1000;
}
ul.exo-menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.cabeza, ul.manos, ul.corporal {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
/*.container-fluid.megamenusip {
       width: 1200px;
     }*/
.content {
    margin: 50px 100px 0px 100px;
}
.mega-menu-wrap .row {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.exo-menu {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
.exo-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.exo-menu > li > a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.exo-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #23ADF8;
}
.exo-menu i {
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    line-height: 20px !important;
}
li.drop-down, .flyout-right, .flyout-left {
    position: relative;
}
li.drop-down:before {
    content: "f103";
    color: #fff;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
li.drop-down > ul {
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 230px;
}
.drop-down-ul {
    display: none;
}
.flyout-right > ul, .flyout-left > ul {
    top: 0;
    min-width: 230px;
    display: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #365670;
}
li.drop-down > ul > li > a, .flyout-right ul > li > a, .flyout-left ul > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #365670;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #547787;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
}
.flyout-right ul > li > a, .flyout-left ul > li > a {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #B8C7BC;
}
.flyout-mega-wrap {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    min-width: 742px;
}
h4.row.mega-title {
    color: #838383;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
}
.flyout-mega ul > li > a {
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: inherit;
}
.flyout-mega ul > li > a:hover, .flyout-mega ul > li > a:active, .flyout-mega ul > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #ccc !important
}
.animated.fadeIn.mega-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.mega-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.mega-menu-wrap {
    background-color: white;
}
.mm-mega-menu-wrap {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0 rgb(206 206 206 / 51%);
}
h4.row.mega-title {
    color: #838383;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-top: 23px;
}
.mega-menu ul li a {
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: block;
}
ul.stander li a {
    padding: 3px 0px;
}
ul.description li {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    line-height: 8px;
}
ul.description li span {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 85%;
}
a.view-more {
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: #009FE1;
    padding: 2px 10px !important;
    line-height: 21px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
a.view-more:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #0DADEF;
}
ul.icon-des li a i {
    color: #fff;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #009FE1;
    line-height: 35px !important;
}
ul.icon-des li {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}
/*Blog DropDown*/
.Blog {
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    color: #fefefe;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background: #547787;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.Blog .blog-title {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.Blog .blog-des {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.Blog a.view-more {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
/*Images*/
.Images {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    color: #fefefe;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background: #547787;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.Images h4 {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
/*common*/
.flyout-right ul > li > a, .flyout-left ul > li > a, .flyout-mega-wrap {
    background-color: white;
}
/*hover*/
.Blog:hover, .Images:hover, .mega-menu:hover, .drop-down-ul:hover, li.flyout-left > ul:hover, li.flyout-right > ul:hover, .flyout-mega-wrap:hover, li.flyout-left a:hover + ul, li.flyout-right a:hover + ul, .blog-drop-down > a:hover + .Blog, li.drop-down > a:hover + .drop-down-ul, .images-drop-down > a:hover + .Images, .mega-drop-down a:hover + .mega-menu, li.flyout-mega > a:hover + .flyout-mega-wrap {
    display: block;
}
a.toggle-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: black;
    top: 0px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin-top: -13px;
}
.fl-node-5dafd29034e78 {
    z-index: 210 !important;
    position: relative;
}
.megamenusip, .mega-menu, .Images, .Blog, .flyout-right > ul, .flyout-left > ul, li.drop-down > ul {
    z-index: 200;
}
.circle_image02 {
    opacity: 1.0 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50) !important; /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.circle_image02:hover {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important; /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.mega-menu-wrap li {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.mm-mm-icon {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 14px;
    width: 32;
    height: 32;
}
.mm-mm-subtext {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 46px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.mega-drop-down > a > span::after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    content: '\f107';
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.mega-drop-down > a > span.hover::after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    content: '\f106';
}
.mega-drop-down > a > span.hover, .mega-drop-down > a:active {
    color: #23ADF8;
}
.mm-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.mm-grid div:nth-of-type(2) {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 35px;
}
.mm-mm-video {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #EDEDED;
    margin-top: 17px;
    padding: 13px;
    border-radius: 24px;
    height: 47px;
    width: 161px;
}
.mm-mm-video:hover {
    background-color: #23ADF8;
    border-color: #23ADF8;
}
.mm-mm-video a {
    color: #23ADF8;
}
.mm-mm-video:hover a {
    color: white;
}
.mm-mm-video:hover img {
    filter: invert(42%) brightness(180%) contrast(180%);
}
.mega-drop-down a:hover + .mega-menu.hide-block {
    display: none;
}
.mm-mm-flyout {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.animated.mega-menu {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
.mega-menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #23ADF8;
}
.container-fluid {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.mm-grid {
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
h4.row.mega-title {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.row .col-md-2, .row .col-md-3, .row .col-md-4 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 1349px) {
    .fl-node-5dafd29034e79 {
        width: 16%;
    }
    .fl-node-g84bp2nweskf {
       width: 3%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1300px) {
    .mega-menu-wrap {
        width: 1280px;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1299px) {
    .mega-menu-wrap {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1252px) {
    .exo-menu > li > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 30px 22px 32px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1251px) {
    .exo-menu > li > a {padding: 30px 15px 32px;}
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .mega-menu {
        width: 100vw;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1151px) {
    .fl-col-group-equal-height .fl-col.fl-node-5dafd77b08a6a {display: none;}
}
@media (max-width: 1025px) {
    .fl-col-group-equal-height .fl-col.fl-node-5e6078af59549 {display: none;}
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .exo-menu > li:nth-child(1) > a {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%;
        float: left;
    }
    .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .empty {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 789px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    .exo-menu > li > a {
        padding: 30px 12px 32px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .mm-grid {
        margin-bottom: 27px;
    }
    #mm-button-group {display: none;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .mega-menu, .flyout-mega-wrap, .Images, .Blog, .flyout-right > ul, .flyout-left > ul, li.drop-down > ul {
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .flyout-right > ul {
        left: 100%;
    }
    .flyout-left > ul {
        right: 100%;
    }
    .mega-menu-wrap .row {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .fl-builder-content .fl-node-5dafd29034e79 {
        width: calc(100vw - 130px) !important;
    }
    .fl-builder-content .fl-node-5dafd29034e7a {
        width: 130px !important;
    }
    .fl-builder-content .fl-node-g84bp2nweskf {display: none;}
    .fl-node-5dafd2ede7f58 > .fl-module-content {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .exo-menu {
        min-height: 58px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .mega-menu {
        padding: 15px;
    }    
    .animated.mega-menu {
        padding-left: 22px;
        padding-right: 22px;
        margin-left: -22px;
        margin-right: -22px;
    }
    .mm-mega-menu-wrap {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .mega-menu-wrap {
        background-color: transparent;   
    }
    ul.exo-menu.display {
        /*width: 100vw;*/
        left: 0;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 25px;
        background-color: white;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 238px);
    }
    a.toggle-menu {
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .mega-drop-down > a > span::after {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 6px;
    }
    .exo-menu.display a.toggle-menu span {
        display: none;
    }
    .exo-menu.display a.toggle-menu {
        position: absolute;
        right: 21px;
        padding: 20px 4px;
        font-size: 27px;
        margin-top: -70px;
        color: #212121;
    }
    .exo-menu.display a.toggle-menu:hover, a.toggle-menu:hover {
        color: #212121;
    }
    .exo-menu.display a.toggle-menu:before {
        display: block !important;
        font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
        content: '\f00d';
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        color: #B2B2B2;
        font-weight: 900;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: -48px;
    }
    .exo-menu > li > a {
        display: none;
        padding: 30px 8px 32px;
    }
    .exo-menu > li {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDED;
    }
    .exo-menu > li.mm-li-button {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    .display.exo-menu > li {
        width: calc(100vw - 44px);
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    .display.exo-menu > li > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 20px 0;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    .mega-menu, .Images, .Blog, .flyout-right > ul, .flyout-left > ul, li.drop-down > ul {
        position: relative;
    }
    .mega-menu {
        background-color: #F8F8F8;
    }
    #menu-item-1225 {
        margin-top: -5px;
    }
    .fl-builder-content .fl-node-5dafd29034e7a {
        width: 40px !important;
    }
    #see-all-features {content: url('https://global-site.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/what-is-digital-signage-mobile.jpg');}
    #just-4-steps {content: url('https://global-site.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Just-4-steps-to-get-digital-signage-for-your-business-mobile.jpg');}
    .mega-menu.hide-block {
        display: none !important;
    }
    #mm-button-group {display: none;}
    #mm-button-group .mm-mm-button a.fl-button {
        font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: 1px solid #23ADF8 !important;
        background-color: white !important;
        background-clip: border-box;
        border-top-width: 2px;
        border-right-width: 2px;
        border-bottom-width: 2px;
        border-left-width: 2px;
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-top-right-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        /*margin: 10px 0;*/
    }
    .fl-page #mm-mm-button-2 .mm-mm-button a.fl-button {
        border: 1px solid #EDEDED !important;
    }
    .fl-page .mm-mm-button a.fl-button span {
        color: #23ADF8 !important;
    }
    #mm-button-group {
        position: relative;
        bottom: -5px;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        padding-bottom: 24px;
    }
    #mm-button-group li {
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .container-fluid.megamenusip {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    h4.row.mega-title {padding-top: 11px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="header-top">
  <div class="container-fluid megamenusip">
    <ul class="exo-menu">
      <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Product</span></a>
        <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hide-block">
          <div class="mm-mega-menu-wrap">
            <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Instant Digital Signage Platform</h4>
                  <ul class="cabeza">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-features.svg" alt="features" class="mm-mm-icon" />Features</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">See all the features packed into this powerful digital signage platform.</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-templates.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Templates</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">1000’s of professionally designed templates for every business.</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title empty">&nbsp;</h4>
                  <ul class="corporal">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-how-it-works.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />How it Works</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Find out how easy it is to get digital signage for your business.</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-industries.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Industries</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Digital signage is perfect for any business with tailored solutions.</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Get the Player</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Player Software</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">What is Instant Digital Signage?</h4>
                  <div class="mm-grid">
                    <div><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/what-is-digital-signage.jpg" alt="What is Instant Digital Signage?" style="width: 100%;" id="see-all-features"/></div>
                    <div><span class="mm-mm-flyout"> Get an overview of how easy it is to get digital signage</span><br />
                      <button class="mm-mm-video">
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-play.svg" alt="play video" title="play video"> Play Video</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Solutions</span></a>
        <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hide-block">
          <div class="mm-mega-menu-wrap">
            <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Industries</h4>
                  <ul class="cabeza">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-hospitality.svg" alt="features" class="mm-mm-icon" />Hospitality</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Cafe, Restaurant, Fast Food…</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-retail.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Retail</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Cafe, Restaurant, Fast Food…</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-hair-beauty.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Hair &amp; Beauty</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Hair Salons, Nail Salon, Laser…</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title empty">&nbsp;</h4>
                  <ul class="cabeza">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-medical.svg" alt="features" class="mm-mm-icon" />Medical</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Cafe, Restaurant, Fast Food…</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-fitness.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Fitness</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Cafe, Restaurant, Fast Food…</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-more.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />More</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">We have solutions for all industries…</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Use Cases</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="#">Digital Menu Boards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Window Signage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">In-Store Signage</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">About Mandoe</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="#">Enterprise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Partner Program</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Resources</span></a>
        <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hide-block">
          <div class="mm-mega-menu-wrap">
            <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Learn about the product</h4>
                  <ul class="cabeza">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-blog.svg" alt="features" class="mm-mm-icon" />Blog</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Ultimate Guides for getting started, news, updates and much more.</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-case-studies.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Case Studies</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">See how our customers have found success in their journey with us.</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title empty">&nbsp;</h4>
                  <ul class="corporal">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-help-centre.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Help Centre</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Learn how to get started, create content, manage schedules &amp; more.</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Get in Touch</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Learn how it works</h4>
                  <div class="mm-grid">
                    <div><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Just-4-steps-to-get-digital-signage-for-your-business.jpg" alt="Just 4 steps to get digital signage for your business" style="width: 100%;" id="just-4-steps" /></div>
                    <div><span class="mm-mm-flyout">Just 4 steps to get digital signage for your business</span><br />
                      <button class="mm-mm-video">
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-play.svg" alt="play video" title="play video"> Play Video</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/pricing/software-only-pricing/">Pricing</a></li>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-xs-block"><span>|||</span></a>
    </ul>
    <ul id="mm-button-group">
      <li class="mm-li-button" id="mm-mm-button-1">
          <div class="fl-button-wrap mm-mm-button">
            <a href="https://sandbox.mandoemedia.com/signup?origin=mktg_portal" target="_self" class="fl-button" role="button">
                            <span class="fl-button-text">Start Free Trial</span>
                    </a>
            </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mm-li-button" id="mm-mm-button-2">
          <div class="fl-button-wrap mm-mm-button">
            <a href="https://activate.mandoemedia.com" target="_self" class="fl-button" role="button">
                            <span class="fl-button-text">Log In</span>
                    </a>
            </div>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: none;` from `.mega-menu`:

```css
.mega-menu {
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      /*display: none;*/
      position: fixed;
      padding-top: 0;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

Also, use same method to toggle menus for both hover and click handlers. Using different methods for both makes things complicated. I've used `.mega-menu.hide-block` for both small and wide screens in following demo:
Demo on [codesandbox](https://gerny.csb.app/menuBugFix.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mega-drop-down").hover(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
      showMenu(this);
    }
  });

  $(".mega-drop-down").on("click", function() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
      showMenu(this);
    }
  });
  $(".toggle-menu").click(function() {
    $(".exo-menu").toggleClass("display");
    $("#mm-button-group").toggle();
    $(".mega-menu").addClass("hide-block");
  });
});

function showMenu(self) {
  $(".mega-menu")
    .not($(self).children(".mega-menu").toggleClass("hide-block"))
    .addClass("hide-block");
  $(self).find("a span").toggleClass("hover");
  $(".exo-menu")
    .find("a span")
    .not($(self).find("a span"))
    .removeClass("hover");
}
```

```css
.fl-builder-content[data-type="header"].fl-theme-builder-header-sticky {
  z-index: 1000;
}

ul.exo-menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.cabeza,
ul.manos,
ul.corporal {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}


/*.container-fluid.megamenusip {
       width: 1200px;
     }*/

.content {
  margin: 50px 100px 0px 100px;
}

.mega-menu-wrap .row {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.exo-menu {
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.exo-menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.exo-menu>li>a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.exo-menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #23ADF8;
}

.exo-menu i {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  line-height: 20px !important;
}

li.drop-down,
.flyout-right,
.flyout-left {
  position: relative;
}

li.drop-down:before {
  content: "f103";
  color: #fff;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

li.drop-down>ul {
  left: 0px;
  min-width: 230px;
}

.drop-down-ul {
  display: none;
}

.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul {
  top: 0;
  min-width: 230px;
  display: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #365670;
}

li.drop-down>ul>li>a,
.flyout-right ul>li>a,
.flyout-left ul>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #365670;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #547787;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
  transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
}

.flyout-right ul>li>a,
.flyout-left ul>li>a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #B8C7BC;
}

.flyout-mega-wrap {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  min-width: 742px;
}

h4.row.mega-title {
  color: #838383;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.flyout-mega ul>li>a {
  font-size: 90%;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.flyout-mega ul>li>a:hover,
.flyout-mega ul>li>a:active,
.flyout-mega ul>li>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: #ccc !important
}

.animated.fadeIn.mega-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.mega-menu {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  /*display: none;*/
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.mega-menu-wrap {
  background-color: white;
}

.mm-mega-menu-wrap {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0 rgb(206 206 206 / 51%);
}

h4.row.mega-title {
  color: #838383;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  padding-top: 23px;
}

.mega-menu ul li a {
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
}

ul.stander li a {
  padding: 3px 0px;
}

ul.description li {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  line-height: 8px;
}

ul.description li span {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 85%;
}

a.view-more {
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #009FE1;
  padding: 2px 10px !important;
  line-height: 21px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

a.view-more:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #0DADEF;
}

ul.icon-des li a i {
  color: #fff;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #009FE1;
  line-height: 35px !important;
}

ul.icon-des li {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}


/*Blog DropDown*/

.Blog {
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  color: #fefefe;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background: #547787;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.Blog .blog-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.Blog .blog-des {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 90%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.Blog a.view-more {
  margin-top: 0px;
}


/*Images*/

.Images {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  color: #fefefe;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background: #547787;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.Images h4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*common*/

.flyout-right ul>li>a,
.flyout-left ul>li>a,
.flyout-mega-wrap {
  background-color: white;
}


/*hover*/

.Blog:hover,
.Images:hover,
.mega-menu:hover,
.drop-down-ul:hover,
li.flyout-left>ul:hover,
li.flyout-right>ul:hover,
.flyout-mega-wrap:hover,
li.flyout-left a:hover+ul,
li.flyout-right a:hover+ul,
.blog-drop-down>a:hover+.Blog,
li.drop-down>a:hover+.drop-down-ul,
.images-drop-down>a:hover+.Images,
.mega-drop-down a:hover+.mega-menu,
li.flyout-mega>a:hover+.flyout-mega-wrap {
  display: block;
}

a.toggle-menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: black;
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-top: -13px;
}

.fl-node-5dafd29034e78 {
  z-index: 210 !important;
  position: relative;
}

.megamenusip,
.mega-menu,
.Images,
.Blog,
.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul,
li.drop-down>ul {
  z-index: 200;
}

.circle_image02 {
  opacity: 1.0 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50) !important;
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.circle_image02:hover {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.mega-menu-wrap li {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.mm-mm-icon {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 14px;
  width: 32;
  height: 32;
}

.mm-mm-subtext {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 46px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.mega-drop-down>a>span::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
  content: '\f107';
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.mega-drop-down>a>span.hover::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
  content: '\f106';
}

.mega-drop-down>a>span.hover,
.mega-drop-down>a:active {
  color: #23ADF8;
}

.mm-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.mm-grid div:nth-of-type(2) {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 35px;
}

.mm-mm-video {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #EDEDED;
  margin-top: 17px;
  padding: 13px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  height: 47px;
  width: 161px;
}

.mm-mm-video:hover {
  background-color: #23ADF8;
  border-color: #23ADF8;
}

.mm-mm-video a {
  color: #23ADF8;
}

.mm-mm-video:hover a {
  color: white;
}

.mm-mm-video:hover img {
  filter: invert(42%) brightness(180%) contrast(180%);
}

.mega-drop-down a:hover+.mega-menu.hide-block {
  display: none;
}

.mm-mm-flyout {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.animated.mega-menu {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

.mega-menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #23ADF8;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.mm-grid {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

h4.row.mega-title {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.row .col-md-2,
.row .col-md-3,
.row .col-md-4 {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1349px) {
  .fl-node-5dafd29034e79 {
    width: 16%;
  }
  .fl-node-g84bp2nweskf {
    width: 3%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1300px) {
  .mega-menu-wrap {
    width: 1280px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1299px) {
  .mega-menu-wrap {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1252px) {
  .exo-menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 30px 22px 32px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1251px) {
  .exo-menu>li>a {
    padding: 30px 15px 32px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .mega-menu {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1151px) {
  .fl-col-group-equal-height .fl-col.fl-node-5dafd77b08a6a {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1025px) {
  .fl-col-group-equal-height .fl-col.fl-node-5e6078af59549 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .exo-menu>li:nth-child(1)>a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .empty {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 789px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  .exo-menu>li>a {
    padding: 30px 12px 32px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .mm-grid {
    margin-bottom: 27px;
  }
  #mm-button-group {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .mega-menu,
  .flyout-mega-wrap,
  .Images,
  .Blog,
  .flyout-right>ul,
  .flyout-left>ul,
  li.drop-down>ul {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .flyout-right>ul {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .flyout-left>ul {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .mega-menu-wrap .row {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}

.mega-menu.hide-block {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .fl-builder-content .fl-node-5dafd29034e79 {
    width: calc(100vw - 130px) !important;
  }
  .fl-builder-content .fl-node-5dafd29034e7a {
    width: 130px !important;
  }
  .fl-builder-content .fl-node-g84bp2nweskf {
    display: none;
  }
  .fl-node-5dafd2ede7f58>.fl-module-content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .exo-menu {
    min-height: 58px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mega-menu {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .animated.mega-menu {
    padding-left: 22px;
    padding-right: 22px;
    margin-left: -22px;
    margin-right: -22px;
  }
  .mm-mega-menu-wrap {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .mega-menu-wrap {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  ul.exo-menu.display {
    /*width: 100vw;*/
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 238px);
  }
  a.toggle-menu {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mega-drop-down>a>span::after {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 6px;
  }
  .exo-menu.display a.toggle-menu span {
    display: none;
  }
  .exo-menu.display a.toggle-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 21px;
    padding: 20px 4px;
    font-size: 27px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    color: #212121;
  }
  .exo-menu.display a.toggle-menu:hover,
  a.toggle-menu:hover {
    color: #212121;
  }
  .exo-menu.display a.toggle-menu:before {
    display: block !important;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    content: '\f00d';
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: #B2B2B2;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: -48px;
  }
  .exo-menu>li>a {
    display: none;
    padding: 30px 8px 32px;
  }
  .exo-menu>li {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDED;
  }
  .exo-menu>li.mm-li-button {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .display.exo-menu>li {
    width: calc(100vw - 44px);
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .display.exo-menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .mega-menu,
  .Images,
  .Blog,
  .flyout-right>ul,
  .flyout-left>ul,
  li.drop-down>ul {
    position: relative;
  }
  .mega-menu {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
  }
  #menu-item-1225 {
    margin-top: -5px;
  }
  .fl-builder-content .fl-node-5dafd29034e7a {
    width: 40px !important;
  }
  #see-all-features {
    content: url('https://global-site.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/what-is-digital-signage-mobile.jpg');
  }
  #just-4-steps {
    content: url('https://global-site.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Just-4-steps-to-get-digital-signage-for-your-business-mobile.jpg');
  }
  #mm-button-group {
    display: none;
  }
  #mm-button-group .mm-mm-button a.fl-button {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #23ADF8 !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    /*margin: 10px 0;*/
  }
  .fl-page #mm-mm-button-2 .mm-mm-button a.fl-button {
    border: 1px solid #EDEDED !important;
  }
  .fl-page .mm-mm-button a.fl-button span {
    color: #23ADF8 !important;
  }
  #mm-button-group {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }
  #mm-button-group li {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .container-fluid.megamenusip {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
  h4.row.mega-title {
    padding-top: 11px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="header-top">
  <div class="container-fluid megamenusip">
    <ul class="exo-menu">
      <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Product</span></a>
        <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hide-block">
          <div class="mm-mega-menu-wrap">
            <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Instant Digital Signage Platform</h4>
                  <ul class="cabeza">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-features.svg" alt="features" class="mm-mm-icon" />Features</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">See all the features packed into this powerful digital signage platform.</span></li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-templates.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Templates</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">1000’s of professionally designed templates for every business.</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title empty">&nbsp;</h4>
                  <ul class="corporal">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-how-it-works.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />How it Works</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Find out how easy it is to get digital signage for your business.</span></li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-industries.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Industries</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Digital signage is perfect for any business with tailored solutions.</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Get the Player</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Player Software</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">What is Instant Digital Signage?</h4>
                  <div class="mm-grid">
                    <div><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/what-is-digital-signage.jpg" alt="What is Instant Digital Signage?" style="width: 100%;" id="see-all-features" /></div>
                    <div><span class="mm-mm-flyout"> Get an overview of how easy it is to get digital signage</span><br />
                      <button class="mm-mm-video">
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-play.svg" alt="play video" title="play video"> Play Video</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Solutions</span></a>
        <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hide-block">
          <div class="mm-mega-menu-wrap">
            <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Industries</h4>
                  <ul class="cabeza">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-hospitality.svg" alt="features" class="mm-mm-icon" />Hospitality</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Cafe, Restaurant, Fast Food…</span></li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-retail.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Retail</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Cafe, Restaurant, Fast Food…</span></li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-hair-beauty.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Hair &amp; Beauty</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Hair Salons, Nail Salon, Laser…</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title empty">&nbsp;</h4>
                  <ul class="cabeza">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-medical.svg" alt="features" class="mm-mm-icon" />Medical</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Cafe, Restaurant, Fast Food…</span></li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-fitness.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Fitness</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Cafe, Restaurant, Fast Food…</span></li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-more.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />More</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">We have solutions for all industries…</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Use Cases</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="#">Digital Menu Boards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Window Signage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">In-Store Signage</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">About Mandoe</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="#">Enterprise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Partner Program</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Resources</span></a>
        <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hide-block">
          <div class="mm-mega-menu-wrap">
            <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Learn about the product</h4>
                  <ul class="cabeza">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-blog.svg" alt="features" class="mm-mm-icon" />Blog</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Ultimate Guides for getting started, news, updates and much more.</span></li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-case-studies.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Case Studies</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">See how our customers have found success in their journey with us.</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title empty">&nbsp;</h4>
                  <ul class="corporal">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-help-centre.svg" alt="templates" class="mm-mm-icon" />Help Centre</a> <span class="mm-mm-subtext">Learn how to get started, create content, manage schedules &amp; more.</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Get in Touch</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Learn how it works</h4>
                  <div class="mm-grid">
                    <div><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Just-4-steps-to-get-digital-signage-for-your-business.jpg" alt="Just 4 steps to get digital signage for your business" style="width: 100%;" id="just-4-steps" /></div>
                    <div><span class="mm-mm-flyout">Just 4 steps to get digital signage for your business</span><br />
                      <button class="mm-mm-video">
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/icon-play.svg" alt="play video" title="play video"> Play Video</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/pricing/software-only-pricing/">Pricing</a></li>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-xs-block"><span>|||</span></a>
    </ul>
    <ul id="mm-button-group">
      <li class="mm-li-button" id="mm-mm-button-1">
        <div class="fl-button-wrap mm-mm-button">
          <a href="https://sandbox.mandoemedia.com/signup?origin=mktg_portal" target="_self" class="fl-button" role="button">
            <span class="fl-button-text">Start Free Trial</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mm-li-button" id="mm-mm-button-2">
        <div class="fl-button-wrap mm-mm-button">
          <a href="https://activate.mandoemedia.com" target="_self" class="fl-button" role="button">
            <span class="fl-button-text">Log In</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The website owner wants the mega menus to display on hover for desktop, and on click/tap for tablet/mobile.

Comment: I see. With latest changes, the above demo should let you resize on desktop as well.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. I receive a message I can award the bounty in 6 hours (for a reason I don't understand), which I will.

Comment: One bug I see is when you open say, the Products mega menu, while it is open, try to close the mobile menu, it doesn't close properly.

Comment: Solution is simple when you interact with mobile menu, hide all mega menus using `$(".mega-menu").addClass("hide-block")`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! I've created a [2nd question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71435035/jquery-click-to-open-mega-menu-scroll-to-where-click-took-place) you might be interested in.