# how to scroll vertically through a mega menu on mobile

Tags: css

Previously I had `.container-fluid.megamenusip {overflow-y: scroll}` which worked until [it didn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71463542/667903) (it broke the menu open/close button).

In a mobile view how do I scroll through each mega menu?

If I add back `.container-fluid.megamenusip {overflow-y: scroll}` it doesn't resolve the issue.

The live site [is here](https://mandoedev.wpengine.com/).

Help appreciated.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => { 
  document.querySelector(':root').style
    .setProperty('--vh', window.innerHeight/100 + 'px');
})    
window.addEventListener('resize', () => { 
  document.querySelector(':root').style
    .setProperty('--vh', window.innerHeight/100 + 'px');
})
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".mega-drop-down").hover(function() {
            if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
                showMenu(this);
            }
        });
        
        jQuery(".mega-drop-down").click(function() {
            if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
                showMenu(this);
            }
        });        
    
        jQuery(".mega-drop-down").on("click", function() {
            if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                showMenu(this);
                this.scrollIntoView(); //{block:nearest}
            }
        });
        
        jQuery(".toggle-menu").click(function() {
            jQuery("#mm-mm-burger").toggleClass("display");
            jQuery("#megamenusip").toggleClass("display");
            jQuery("#mm-logo").toggleClass("fixed");
            jQuery(".exo-menu").toggleClass("display");
            jQuery("#mm-button-group").toggle();
            jQuery(".mega-menu").addClass("hide-block");
        });
    });
    
    function showMenu(self) {
        jQuery(".mega-menu")
            .not(jQuery(self).children(".mega-menu").toggleClass("hide-block"))
            .addClass("hide-block");
        jQuery(self).find("a span").toggleClass("hover");
        jQuery(".exo-menu")
            .find("a span")
            .not(jQuery(self).find("a span"))
            .removeClass("hover");
    }
```

```css
.fl-builder-content[data-type="header"].fl-theme-builder-header-sticky {
    z-index: 1000;
}

ul.exo-menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.cabeza,
ul.manos,
ul.corporal {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.content {
    margin: 50px 100px 0px 100px;
}

.mega-menu-wrap .row {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.exo-menu {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

.exo-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.exo-menu>li>a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.exo-menu>li>a:hover {
    color: #23ADF8;
}

.exo-menu i {
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    line-height: 20px !important;
}

li.drop-down,
.flyout-right,
.flyout-left {
    position: relative;
}

li.drop-down:before {
    content: "f103";
    color: #fff;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

li.drop-down>ul {
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 230px;
}

.drop-down-ul {
    display: none;
}

.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul {
    top: 0;
    min-width: 230px;
    display: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #365670;
}

.flyout-mega-wrap {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    min-width: 742px;
}

h4.row.mega-title {
    color: #838383;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.flyout-mega ul>li>a {
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: inherit;
}

.flyout-mega ul>li>a:hover,
.flyout-mega ul>li>a:active,
.flyout-mega ul>li>a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #ccc !important
}

.animated.fadeIn.mega-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.mega-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    /*display: none;*/
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 0;
    /*padding-top: 10px;*/
}

.mega-menu-wrap {
    background-color: white;
}

.mm-mega-menu-wrap {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0 rgb(206 206 206 / 51%);
}

h4.row.mega-title {
    color: #838383;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-top: 23px;
}

.mega-menu ul li a {
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: block;
}

ul.stander li a {
    padding: 3px 0px;
}

ul.description li {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    line-height: 8px;
}

ul.description li span {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 85%;
}

a.view-more {
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: #009FE1;
    padding: 2px 10px !important;
    line-height: 21px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}

a.view-more:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #0DADEF;
}

ul.icon-des li a i {
    color: #fff;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #009FE1;
    line-height: 35px !important;
}

ul.icon-des li {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}


/*Blog DropDown*/

.Blog {
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    color: #fefefe;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background: #547787;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.Blog .blog-title {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.Blog .blog-des {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.Blog a.view-more {
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/*Images*/

.Images {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    color: #fefefe;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background: #547787;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.Images h4 {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*common*/

.flyout-right ul>li>a,
.flyout-left ul>li>a,
.flyout-mega-wrap {
    background-color: white;
}


/*hover*/

.Blog:hover,
.Images:hover,
.mega-menu:hover,
.drop-down-ul:hover,
li.flyout-left>ul:hover,
li.flyout-right>ul:hover,
.flyout-mega-wrap:hover,
li.flyout-left a:hover+ul,
li.flyout-right a:hover+ul,
.blog-drop-down>a:hover+.Blog,
li.drop-down>a:hover+.drop-down-ul,
.images-drop-down>a:hover+.Images,
.mega-drop-down a:hover+.mega-menu,
li.flyout-mega>a:hover+.flyout-mega-wrap {
    display: block;
}

.fl-node-5dafd29034e78 {
    z-index: 210 !important;
    position: relative;
}

.megamenusip,
.mega-menu,
.Images,
.Blog,
.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul,
li.drop-down>ul {
    z-index: 200;
}

.circle_image02 {
    opacity: 1.0 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50) !important;
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.circle_image02:hover {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.mega-menu-wrap li {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    /*padding-right: 30px;*/
}

.mm-mm-icon {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 14px;
    width: 32;
    height: 32;
}

.mm-mm-subtext {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 46px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.mega-drop-down>a>span::after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    content: '\f107';
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.mega-drop-down>a>span.hover::after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    content: '\f106';
}

.mega-drop-down>a>span.hover,
.mega-drop-down>a:active {
    color: #23ADF8;
}

.mm-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.mm-grid div:nth-of-type(2) {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 35px;
}

.mm-mm-video {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #EDEDED;
    margin-top: 17px;
    padding: 13px;
    border-radius: 24px;
    height: 47px;
    width: 161px;
}

.mm-mm-video:hover {
    background-color: #23ADF8;
    border-color: #23ADF8;
}

.mm-mm-video a {
    color: #23ADF8;
}

.mm-mm-video:hover a {
    color: white;
}

.mm-mm-video:hover img {
    filter: invert(42%) brightness(180%) contrast(180%);
}

.mega-drop-down a:hover+.mega-menu.hide-block {
    display: none;
}

.mm-mm-flyout {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.animated.mega-menu {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

.mega-menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #23ADF8;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.mm-grid {
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

h4.row.mega-title {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.row .col-md-2,
.row .col-md-3,
.row .col-md-4,
.row .col-md-6 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1359px) {
    .exo-menu>li>a {
        display: block;
        padding: 30px 22px 32px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1358px) {
    .exo-menu>li>a {
        padding: 30px 15px 32px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1252px) and (max-width: 1358px) {
    .animated.fadeIn.mega-menu {
      margin-top: 32px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1349px) {
    .fl-node-5dafd29034e79 {
        width: 16%;
    }
    .fl-node-g84bp2nweskf {
        width: 3.5%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1340px) {
    .mega-menu-wrap {
        width: 1278px;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1339px) {
    .mega-menu-wrap {
        width: calc(100vw - 80px);
        margin: auto;
    }  
}
@media (max-width: 1251px) {
    .exo-menu>li>a {
        padding: 30px 15px 32px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1251px) {
    .animated.fadeIn.mega-menu {
        margin-top: 32px;
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .mega-menu {
        width: 100vw;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1151px) {
    .fl-col-group-equal-height .fl-col.fl-node-5dafd77b08a6a {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1025px) {
    .fl-col-group-equal-height .fl-col.fl-node-5e6078af59549 {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .exo-menu>li:nth-child(1)>a {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .row .col-md-2 {
        width: 12%;
        margin-right: 3%;
    }
    .row .col-md-3 {
        width: 21.25%;
        margin-right: 4%;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .row .col-md-3:last-of-type {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .row .industries .col-md-3 {
        width: 20.25%;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%;
        float: left;
    }
    .col-md-6 .col-md-6 {
        width: 47%;
    }
    #col-use-cases {
        margin-left: 2.5%;
        margin-right: 1.5%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .empty {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 789px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    .exo-menu>li>a {
        padding: 30px 12px 32px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 788px) {
    .exo-menu>li>a {
        padding: 30px 13px 32px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .mm-grid {margin-bottom: 27px;}
    .mega-menu {background-color: white;}
    .mega-menu-wrap {min-height: 306px;}
    #mm-button-group {display: none !important;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .mega-menu,
    .flyout-mega-wrap,
    .Images,
    .Blog,
    .flyout-right>ul,
    .flyout-left>ul,
    li.drop-down>ul {
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .flyout-right>ul {
        left: 100%;
    }

    .flyout-left>ul {
        right: 100%;
    }

    .mega-menu-wrap .row {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        /*padding: 0 15px;*/
    }
}
.mega-menu.hide-block {
    display: none !important;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #mm-logo {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: white;
        padding-left: 23px;
    }

    #mm-logo.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        background: white;
        /*left: 23px;*/
        z-index: 55;
    }

    .admin-bar #mm-logo {
        position: fixed;
        top: 46px;
    }

    .fl-page header.fl-builder-content {
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .fl-builder-content .fl-node-5dafd29034e79 {
        width: calc(100vw - 130px) !important;
    }

    .fl-builder-content .fl-node-5dafd29034e7a {
        width: 130px !important;
    }

    .fl-builder-content .fl-node-g84bp2nweskf {
        display: none;
    }

    .fl-module.fl-module-html.fl-node-3p7sb46cwvqu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
    }

    .fl-node-5dafd2ede7f58>.fl-module-content {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .exo-menu {
        min-height: 58px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mega-menu {
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .animated.mega-menu {
        padding-left: 22px;
        padding-right: 22px;
        margin-left: -22px;
        margin-right: -22px;
    }

    .animated.fadeIn.mega-menu {
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .mm-mega-menu-wrap {
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .mega-menu-wrap {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    ul.exo-menu.display {
        left: 0;
        top: 0px;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: white;
        min-height: calc((100 * var(--vh)) - 210px);
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .admin-bar ul.exo-menu.display {
        min-height: calc(100vh - 256px);
    }
    
    .admin-bar a.toggle-menu {
        top: 64px;
    }

    .mega-drop-down,
    .bg-white {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .mega-drop-down>a>span::after {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 6px;
    }

    .exo-menu.display a.toggle-menu span {
        display: none;
    }

    a.toggle-menu {
        position: fixed;
        color: black;
        top: 8px;
        right: 0;
        padding: 4px 22px;
        font-size: 27px;
        z-index: 55;
        color: #212121;
    }
    a.toggle-menu::before {
        display: block !important;
        font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
        content: url("/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/images/menu-open.svg");
        font-weight: 900;
        color: #000000;
    }
    a.toggle-menu.display::before {
        content: url("/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/images/menu-close.svg");
        color: #B2B2B2;
        margin-right: 6px;
    }
    /*.exo-menu.display a.toggle-menu::before {
        display: block !important;
        font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
        content: '\f00d';
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        color: #B2B2B2;
        font-weight: 900;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }*/

    .exo-menu>li>a {
        display: none;
        padding: 30px 8px 32px;
    }

    .exo-menu>li {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDED;
    }

    .exo-menu>li.mm-li-button {
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    .display.exo-menu>li {
        width: calc(100vw - 44px);
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }

    .display.exo-menu>li>a {
        display: block;
        padding: 20px 0;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .mega-menu,
    .Images,
    .Blog,
    .flyout-right>ul,
    .flyout-left>ul,
    li.drop-down>ul {
        position: relative;
    }

    .mega-menu {
        background-color: #F8F8F8;
    }

    #menu-item-1225 {
        margin-top: -5px;
    }

    .fl-builder-content .fl-node-5dafd29034e7a {
        width: 40px !important;
    }

    #see-all-features {
        content: url('/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/images/what-is-digital-signage-mobile.jpg');
    }

    #just-4-steps {
        content: url('/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/images/Just-4-steps-to-get-digital-signage-for-your-business-mobile.jpg');
    }

    #mm-button-group {
        display: none;
    }

    #mm-button-group .mm-mm-button a.fl-button {
        font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: 1px solid #23ADF8 !important;
        background-color: white !important;
        background-clip: border-box;
        border-top-width: 2px;
        border-right-width: 2px;
        border-bottom-width: 2px;
        border-left-width: 2px;
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-top-right-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        /*margin: 10px 0;*/
    }

    .fl-page #mm-mm-button-2 .mm-mm-button a.fl-button {
        border: 1px solid #EDEDED !important;
    }

    .fl-page .mm-mm-button a.fl-button span {
        color: #23ADF8 !important;
    }

    #mm-button-group {
        position: relative;
        /*bottom: 5px;*/
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px 22px 20px 22px;
        /*margin-bottom: 22px;*/
    }

    #mm-button-group li {
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
        background-color: white;
    }

    .container-fluid.megamenusip {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        top: 66px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        justify-content: stretch;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .container-fluid.megamenusip.display {
            height: calc(100% - 56px);
    }

    header .fl-col-group.fl-col-group-equal-height.fl-col-group-custom-width {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        background: white;
        position: fixed;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }

    h4.row.mega-title {
        padding-top: 11px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="header-top">
  <a href="#" id="mm-mm-burger" class="toggle-menu visible-xs-block"></a>
  <div class="container-fluid megamenusip">
    <ul class="exo-menu">
      <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Product</span></a>
        <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hide-block">
          <div class="mm-mega-menu-wrap">
            <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Instant Digital Signage Platform</h4>
                  <ul class="cabeza">
                    <li><a href="/features/">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/templates/">Templates</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title empty">&nbsp;</h4>
                  <ul class="corporal">
                    <li><a href="/how-it-works/">How it Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/industries/">Industries</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Get the Player</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="/hardware/">Hardware</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/download-player/">Player Software</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">What is Instant Digital Signage?</h4>
                  <div class="mm-grid">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Solutions</span></a>
        <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hide-block">
          <div class="mm-mega-menu-wrap">
            <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4 class="row mega-title">Industries</h4>
                        <ul class="cabeza">
                            <li><a href="/industries/hospitality/">Hospitality</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/industries/cafe/">Retail</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/industries/hair-salon/">Hair &amp; Beauty</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4 class="row mega-title empty">&nbsp;</h4>
                        <ul class="cabeza">
                            <li><a href="/industries/cafe/">Medical</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/industries/gym/">Fitness</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/industries/">More</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" id="col-use-cases">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Use Cases</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="/usecase/digital-menuboards/">Digital Menu Boards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/usecase/window-signage/">Window Signage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/usecase/instore-signage/">In-Store Signage</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">About Mandoe</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="/enterprise/">Enterprise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/customers/">Customers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/partner-program">Partner Program</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Resources</span></a>
        <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hide-block">
          <div class="mm-mega-menu-wrap">
            <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Learn about the product</h4>
                  <ul class="cabeza">
                    <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog/topic/case-studies/">Case Studies</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title empty">&nbsp;</h4>
                  <ul class="corporal">
                    <li><a href="https://help.mandoemedia.com">Help Centre</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Get in Touch</h4>
                  <ul class="manos">
                    <li><a href="/about-us/">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact/sales/">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact/support">Support</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h4 class="row mega-title">Learn how it works</h4>
                  <div class="mm-grid">
                    <div></div>
                    <div><span class="mm-mm-flyout">Just 4 steps to get digital signage for your business</span><br />
                      <button class="mm-mm-video">
                      <a href="#">Play Video</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="bg-white"><a href="/pricing/software-only-pricing/">Pricing</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="mm-button-group">
      <li class="mm-li-button" id="mm-mm-button-1">
          <div class="fl-button-wrap mm-mm-button">
            <a href="https://sandbox.mandoemedia.com/signup?origin=mktg_portal" target="_self" class="fl-button" role="button">
                            <span class="fl-button-text">Start Free Trial</span>
                    </a>
            </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mm-li-button" id="mm-mm-button-2">
          <div class="fl-button-wrap mm-mm-button">
            <a href="https://activate.mandoemedia.com" target="_self" class="fl-button" role="button">
                            <span class="fl-button-text">Log In</span>
                    </a>
            </div>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel it's a naive idea, but i'll just say it :"

Comment: Have you tried giving each `li.mega-drop-down` a specific `max-height` and then `overflow-y` of vertical`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to keep header fixed for mobiles. Already real-estate is very less there. For mobiles make header relative/static and for desktops keep it sticky.

I couldn't get your code in OP working like the website. So tried things on the website itself using Dev tools.

 Following CSS makes header non fixed for small screens:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 header .fl-col-group.fl-col-group-equal-height.fl-col-group-custom-width {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  background: white;
  position: absolute; /* <-- */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
 }


 .fl-module.fl-module-html.fl-node-3p7sb46cwvqu {
  /* position: absolute; */ /* <-- */
  top: 20px;
 }


 .container-fluid.megamenusip {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: 66px;
  position: absolute; /* <-- */
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  justify-content: stretch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }

}
```

I think you make `<header>` sticky on big screens and relative on small ones. And don't use fixed on any children used absolute. For small screens make megamenusip non absolute.
Or take the megamenu part out of the `<header>` and make it floating relative to the scrolling parent. For wide screens use position `fixed` and for small use `absolute`.

Comment: Simply beautiful. You don't know what a difference this makes. Thank you.

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71554668/click-behaviour-interfering-with-hover-behaviour) is the last question I have to bother you with. Any chance for some help?